# Using Regex to edit a column in R

Tags: r, regex, text, edit

This problem is about writing a regex to edit a column of industry names that I have in a data frame.

To create an example data frame here is some code:

```
Industries<-c("LEISURE - Restaurants", "FINANCIAL SERVICES - Closed End Fund - Equity", "AEROSPACE/DEFENSE - Aerospace/Defense Products & Services", "METALS & MINING -  Industrial Metals & Minerals")
Industries<-data.frame(Industries)
```

I have a column that is populated with words strings such as:

```
LEISURE - Restaurants
FINANCIAL SERVICES - Closed End Fund - Equity
AEROSPACE/DEFENSE - Aerospace/Defense Products & Services
METALS & MINING -  Industrial Metals & Minerals
```

I want to preserve everything to the left of the first hyphen while discarding everything else.
Desired output:

```
LEISURE
FINANCIAL SERVICES
AEROSPACE/DEFENSE
METALS & MINING
```

I have tried:

```
stringi::stri_trim_right(Industries[,1], pattern = "[-]")
```

[1] "LEISURE -"                              "FINANCIAL SERVICES - Closed End Fund -"
[3] "AEROSPACE/DEFENSE -"                    "METALS & MINING -"

```
stringi::stri_trim_right(Industries[,1], pattern = "[A-Z]")
```

[1] "LEISURE - R"                                        "FINANCIAL SERVICES - Closed End Fund - E"
[3] "AEROSPACE/DEFENSE - Aerospace/Defense Products & S" "METALS & MINING -  Industrial Metals & M"

```
gsub("[^A-Z]","", Industries[,1])
```

[1] "LEISURER"              "FINANCIALSERVICESCEFE" "AEROSPACEDEFENSEADPS"  "METALSMININGIMM"

All are close, but not what I need.  Suggestions? Relevant post?

Comment: Try `sub("\\s*-.*", "", Industries[,1])`

Comment: that would do it.  Thanks!